# How to attach a remote container using vscode command line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I want to use a command line tool to attach a remote container. I tried this command (see below), but it's of no use. Does anyone know the correct command?

```bsh
code --folder-uri vscode-remote://dev-container+4aaf623ee98a52fa311226a2c619be19addfa221c090b9a3bc37e7cba03a7fce/easycv
```

Comment: Can you specify what you meant by _of no use_ ?
I tried to attach to a container without use of `devcontainer.json`, so the uri contained `attached-container` instead of `dev-container`, so the command was:
  `code --folder-uri vscode-remote://attached-container+7b22636f6e7461696e65724e616d65223a222f70726963656c6573735f686f70706572227d/app`.
Replacing the container id with the container name was similar, so I got an error message with id or name being shown as garbage.
But a prompt appeared asking to choose a running container, and from there it was possible to attach the wanted container.

Answer (score 6):

To automate this, I created this cross-plattform-ish solution:

https://github.com/geircode/vscode-attach-to-container-script

This solution creates the hex based on the name of the running container.

Windows CMD script:

```
docker run --rm geircode/string_to_hex bash string_to_hex.bash "<container_name>" > vscode_remote_hex.txt

set /p vscode_remote_hex=<vscode_remote_hex.txt

code --folder-uri=vscode-remote://attached-container+%vscode_remote_hex%/app
```

Comment: Since I stumbled on this during my search, I had a hard time getting this to work until I realized that it was because I was using Docker Desktop for Linux. Docker Desktop for Linux uses a different context than the default Docker context, so you'll need to modify the payload of your JSON string in this command to:

```{"conainerName":"CONTAINER_NAME","settings":{"context":"desktop-linux"}}```

The new addition is `context` within the `settings` object.

Answer (score 4):

That string of characters after dev-container+ is an ascii path to your dev container folder encoded in hexadecimal.

To open a folder in a container you can use the following style command:

```
code --folder-uri=vscode-remote://dev-container%2B{path-in-hex}/{path-inside-container}
```

For example to open the folder `/workspaces/test` in the development container located in `/Users/jkells/projects/vscode-devcontainer` I use the following CLI command.

```
code --folder-uri=vscode-remote://dev-container%2B2f55736572732f6a6b656c6c732f70726f6a656374732f7673636f64652d646576636f6e7461696e6572/workspaces/test
```

To convert the string `/Users/jkells/projects/vscode-devcontainer` into the hexadecimal `2f55736572732f6a6b656c6c732f70726f6a656374732f7673636f64652d646576636f6e7461696e6572` you can use the following command

```
printf /Users/jkells/projects/vscode-devcontainer | od -A n -t x1 | tr -d '[\n\t ]'
```

Answer (score 3):

This shell script does the job:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case $# in
1) ;;
*) echo "Usage: code-remote-container <directory>"; exit 1 ;;
esac

dir=`echo $(cd $1 && pwd)`
hex=`printf ${dir} | od -A n -t x1 | tr -d '[\n\t ]'`
base=`basename ${dir}`
code --folder-uri="vscode-remote://dev-container%2B${hex}/workspaces/${base}"
```

I have saved it under the name `code-remote-container`, which then e.g. can be used
as:

```sh
code-remote-container .
```

which would open the current directory in the remote container.

Obviously this expects that the remote container has already been setup for `vsc`.

Answer (score 1):

[From Contributor `chrmarti` on Janv. 30, 2023](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/5278#issuecomment-1408712695):

```
code --folder-uri vscode-remote://attached-container+$(printf "$CONTAINER_NAME_OR_ID" | xxd -p)/home
```

[To open a workspace instead of a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74785990/8612123), use `--file-uri` instead, and target the `.code-workspace`:

```
code --file-uri vscode-remote://attached-container+$(printf "$CONTAINER_NAME_OR_ID" | xxd -p)/home/my_workspace.code-workspace
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear: you need to use

```
code --folder-uri vscode-remote://attached-container+<X>/workspaces/bla_bla`
```

where X is containerName in hex encoding.

Container name is this one:

[image: literally name of container(not always biggest label in GUIs)]

[image: you can find it in docker inspect json in field "Name"]

Literally name of container(not always biggest label in GUIs).

You can find it in docker inspect json in field "Name".

Slash at the beginning doesn't matter(can be or not).

To make conversion to hex use online converters, or maybe set /a on Windows (I don't think it's gonna work) or

```bash
printf some_name | od -A n -t x1 | tr -d '[\n\t ]'
```

on Linux(get from **[here](https://gist.github.com/awesomebytes/8494fb216c42bc4a2fcaef6b4937a07e)**)

or you can use bash(like Git Bash)

or use some cross-plattform-ish solution [from Geir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64929306/14892707)

If you want to specify more([like Garrett](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60379221/how-to-attach-a-remote-container-using-vscode-command-line#comment136347916_64929306)) than name - encode json with container settings

Like this

```bash
printf {\"conainerName\":\"ecstatic_shamir\",\"settings\":{\"context\":\"desktop-linux\"}} | od -A n -t x1 | tr -d '[\n\t ]'
```

and put encoded hex number in X.

Don't forget to escape quotation marks in json with backslash "\".

If you want to start container at first - try to replace
`attached-container` with `dev-container`

You can probably use Id instead of Name in X, but it already in hex(do I need to encode it again?), and should i use full version or just short?

My Windows desktop icon to start VSCode with docker container now looks like:

```
"C:\Program Files\VSCode\Code.exe" --folder-uri vscode-remote://attached-container+2f65637374617469635f7368616d6972/workspaces/sapfor
```

where X is `printf ecstatic_shamir | od -A n -t x1 | tr -d '[\n\t ]'`